# ssl : Unable to load certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, pem, der

I have 2 files - CSR.csr and newkey.key, both seem to be in PEM format as follows -

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

MIID....

-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

MI...

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

When I'm trying to read the CSR.csr file, I get the following error :

```
$ openssl x509 -in CSR.csr -text -noout
unable to load certificate
140518720210760:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:698:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

I read that we get this error when the input file is in DER format, so I tried the following -

```
$ openssl x509 -inform DER -in CSR.csr -text -noout
```

but now I get the error -

```
unable to load certificate
140519053051720:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1320:
140519053051720:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:382:Type=X509
```

And it seems this error occurs when the input file is already in PEM format and one tries to read it in DER format.

Really confused how to go about it as I'm new to SSL. Please help!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is not PEM vs. DER but that you are using a certificate request in a place where a certificate is expected. This is clearly shown by the PEM header `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`.

To show the content of a *certificate request* use

```
openssl req -in CSR.csr -text
```

To show the content of a *certificate* use

```
openssl x509 -in CERT.crt -text
```

Answer (score 42):

In my case I was trying to read my cer file and was receiving the error stated above

> openssl x509 -in CSR.csr -text -noout
>   unable to load certificate
>   140518720210760:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:698:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

I had to convert it to a crt file using openssl.

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in <certname>.cer -out <certname>.crt
openssl x509 -in <certname>.crt -text
```

[Here's](https://support.cloudbolt.io/hc/en-us/articles/115002452786-HOWTO-Convert-a-CER-file-to-CRT) the doc i used. I was able to read it using openssl after that

Comment: I also had similar situation and then *still* had a problem when some tool or another included a blank line before some of the non-content markers (like the hyphens lines). Just removing the blank lines solved that problem.

Answer (score 1):

This ERROR also happens on certificates that are not "certificate request" emmited to be signed by a CA (non-CSR certificate) but which are x509 regular certificates from Windows PKI in ".cer" format

In this case, following "Norbert" answer is the good way to solve the problem, converting the certificate in ".crt'

After the file is able to be dumped using:

```sh
openssl x509 -in YOURCERT.crt -noout -text
```

or

```sh
openssl x509 -in YOURCERT.crt -text
```