# OpenSSL unable to load certificate on backend

Tags: c, ssh, openssl, backend, ssh-keys

I created my SSH key [accordingly](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@google.com"
```

This will give me two files:

```
myKey.key.pub
myKey.key
```

Then to convert to pem format I run the [command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26924/how-do-i-convert-a-ssh-keygen-public-key-into-a-format-that-openssl-pem-read-bio):

```
ssh-keygen -f myKey.key.pub -e -m pem > myKey.pem
```

The myKey.pem is the file to be provided for the backend [C program](http://simplestcodings.blogspot.com/2010/08/secure-server-client-using-openssl-in-c.html).

However, I have been stuck with the similar [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630544/cant-get-private-key-with-openssl-no-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-any-p):

```
unable to load certificate
140387178489504:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start     
line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

So, I have followed the [steps](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html):

```
openssl rsa -text -in file.key -inform DER
openssl pkcs8 -in file.key -inform der
```

I also checked some other [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565316/ssl-unable-to-load-certificate) and [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837161/openssl-pem-routinespem-read-biono-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-truste). But the problem still continues:

```
error:0D0680A8:ASN1 encoding routines:ASN1CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1338
error:0D07803A:ASN1 encoding routines:ASN1CHECK_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:390:Type=X509_SIG
```

This certificate will be used with a back-end. Or the way to get the file pem is to actually create and edit it manually? If so, where the [certificate](http://how2ssl.com/articles/working_with_pem_files/) part comes from?

Any suggestions where might be my mistake? All comments are highly welcome :)

Comment: SSH key != SSL certificate. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Jakuje ! I used:  I used: ssh-keygen -f myKey.key.pub -e -m pem > myKey.pem . What should then be used as certificate? Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: To get an SSL/TLS certificate, you use your _private_ key (and in your case and many but not all others an OpenSSH _private_ key file is compatible with OpenSSL) to generate a _Certificate Signing Request_ aka CSR and submit the CSR to a Certificate Authority aka CA to get a certificate. If you want strangers to trust your server you need to use a public CA like Verisign, GoDaddy, LetsEncrypt, etc. If only you or people who know you like friends/coworkers will connect, you can create your own ad-hoc CA with openssl, or even a self-signed cert (no CA).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could happen when your key is password-protected.

you have to decrypt it

$ openssl rsa -in protected.key -out unprotected.key

Then you have to create a new .pem file

$ cat unprotected.key yourcert.crt > yourcert.pem

I also suggest you to check your key and cert files for line endings (openssl does not like Windows ones) and BOM-mark.

Make sure that your certificate is Windows "compatible", most importantly that it doesn't have ^M in the end of each line

If you open it it will look like this:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----^M
MIIDITCCAoqgAwIBAgIQL9+89q6RUm0PmqPfQDQ+mjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBM^M

To solve "this" open it with Write or Notepad++ and have it convert it to Windows "style"

Comment: Hi Cristallo! Thank you so much for your comment. Please check my updated question. To create the pem file, I used: ssh-keygen -f myKey.key.pub -e -m pem > myKey.pem . Anything still missing? Thanks!

Comment: OpenSSL is fine with WIndows line endings (CRLF) or indeed traililng whitespace of any kind in PEM. It does have a problem with BOM (often) or UTF-16 (always), but since PEM by design is only ASCII those aren't needed and most Windows programs won't add them unneeded.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 . Thanks for your comment. I am on Linux. Not Windows.