# Can't get Docker to connect to private registry: error X509

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am running Docker inside a VM (which runs Fedora Server 35) with access to the Internet since I am able to pull public images. I need to pull also some private images but I am running into the following issue:

```sh
docker login myprivateserver:5000
Username: <myusername>
Password: ********
Error response from daemon: Get "https://myprivateserver:5000//v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have followed the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/) but it does not seem to be working. Here is what I have done so far:

- create the directory `/etc/docker/certs.d/myprivateserver:5000`
- copied the cert file to the above route and renamed it as `ca.crt`

I have read a lot of posts here in SO and all of them say that's the way to go but it just doesn't work for me and I don't get why.

Can I get some help? What am I missing here?

> Note: I have obtained the `ca.cert` file by accessing the URL `https://myprivateserver:5000` from the browser and then downloading the file from there.

> Note 2: `myprivateserver` is a placeholder I use in order to no discard the current URL (security reasons)

Comment: Have you checked the content of your certificate ? (`openssl x509 -text -noout -in /etc/docker/certs.d/myprivateserver:5000/ca.crt`)

Comment: running that command shows `unable to load certificate`

Comment: so since I got the cert from the browser it downloaded as `.cer` I renamed that into `.crt` but that is wrong. The correct way to convert `CER` into `CRT` is: `openssl x509 -inform DER -in <certname>.cer -out <certname>.crt`. Doing so I was able to properly login into the private repository and pull the needed images.

Comment: credits goes to: @Zeitounator for put me in the right path and this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51290883/719427